# "circular" Screen setup Xrandr

Tags: xrandr

I'm installing a new setup with 2 screens plugged onto a laptop (primary). One on the left, one on the right.
Right now Xrandr  looks like this :

> eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+1050+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
>
> DP-1 connected 1600x900+2416+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 434mm x 236mm
>
> DP-2 connected 1050x1680+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm

The position setup is DP-2 -- eDP-1 -- DP-1

My question is, is that **possible** to have a "circular" configuration so that going on the left from DP-2 brings to DP-1 & reversely going on the right from DP-1 brings to DP-2 like a pacman board ?

I tried this command `xrandr --output DP-2 --right-of DP-1 --left-of eDP-1`  Which is syntacticly correct (not raising an error), but doesn't change anything.